# typescript : get all combinations of fixed length without repetition

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, combinations

I have the following input :

```
interface Option{
  name:string
  travelMode:string
}

const options:Option[] = [
  {
    name:"john",
    travelMode:"bus"
  },
  {
    name:"john",
    travelMode:"car"
  },
  {
    name:"kevin",
    travelMode:"bus"
  },
  {
    name:"kevin",
    travelMode:"car"
  },
]
```

I want to get all combinations possible of length 2 inside this collection, to do so, I am doing :

```
const getCombinations=(options:Option[],startIndex:number,combination:Option[],combinationSize:number)=>{
  if (combination.filter(e => e!==undefined).length === combinationSize)
  {
    console.log(combination)
  }
  else if (startIndex<options.length){
    combination[startIndex]=undefined
    getCombinations(options,startIndex+1,combination,combinationSize)


    combination[startIndex]=options[startIndex]
    getCombinations(options,startIndex+1,combination,combinationSize)
  }
}

getCombinations(options,0,[],2)
```

This seems to be working well, I get the following output :

```
[
  undefined,
  undefined,
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'bus' },
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'car' }
]
[
  undefined,
  { name: 'john', travelMode: 'car' },
  undefined,
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'car' }
]
[
  undefined,
  { name: 'john', travelMode: 'car' },
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'bus' },
  undefined
]
[
  { name: 'john', travelMode: 'bus' },
  undefined,
  undefined,
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'car' }
]
[
  { name: 'john', travelMode: 'bus' },
  undefined,
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'bus' },
  undefined
]
[
  { name: 'john', travelMode: 'bus' },
  { name: 'john', travelMode: 'car' },
  undefined,
  undefined
]
```

However, I have one **doubt** and one **remaining problem** :

**My doubt** : why does all the printed combination are of length 4, my breaking condition should normally stop the recursion if we have already 2 defined elements : I don't understand why the last combination printed in my output contains 4 elements (first 2 defined and the remaining 2 undefined) => I am afraid that my program continues to iterate even if it has already 2 elements in its combination, and that's not what I want

**Remaining problem** : I dont want to calculate combination where name is the same, I only want combination with 2 distinct names (john and kevin but not john and john or kevin and kevin)
To do so, I first thought to keep my program like that, calculating everything, and just remove at the end combination with duplicated names, but I quickly realized that it was not the best solution, especially when my input options will have much more data (others individuals and others individuals options).
So I tried the following solution (stop the program if we already have visited the individual) :

```
const getCombinations=(options:Option[],startIndex:number,combination:Option[],combinationSize:number)=>{
  if (combination.filter(e => e!==undefined).length === combinationSize)
  {
    console.log(combination)
  }
  else if (startIndex<options.length){
    combination[startIndex]=undefined
    getCombinations(options,startIndex+1,combination,combinationSize)

    let individualAlreadyVisited = false
    if (startIndex>0)
    {
      for (let i =0;i<startIndex;i++)
      {
        if (combination[i] && combination[i].name===options[startIndex].name)
        {
          individualAlreadyVisited=true
          break
        }
      }
    }

    if (!individualAlreadyVisited)
    {
      combination[startIndex]=options[startIndex]
      getCombinations(options,startIndex+1,combination,combinationSize)
    }
  }
}

getCombinations(options,0,[],2)
```

But this is not working as expected, I am getting the following output :

```
[
  undefined,
  undefined,
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'bus' },
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'car' }
]
[
  undefined,
  { name: 'john', travelMode: 'car' },
  undefined,
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'car' }
]
[
  undefined,
  { name: 'john', travelMode: 'car' },
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'bus' },
  undefined
]
[
  { name: 'john', travelMode: 'bus' },
  undefined,
  { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'bus' },
  undefined
]
```

1. I still have combination with duplicated names, see first element
2. I see some missing combination, for example, the following is not displayed :

   ```
    { name: 'john', travelMode: 'bus' },
    { name: 'kevin', travelMode: 'car' }
   ```

Thanks in advance for your help, I've spend a few hours trying to understand and get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from mutating the array during the recursive steps. That makes the code hard to understand and hard to debug.

I'd use a generator function to go over the array, take the element at the current index, and get combinations from all following elements with n - 1 elements:

```
 function* combine<T>(array: T[], n: number, start = 0, prev: T[] = []) {
   if(n <= 0) {
     yield prev;
     return;
   }

   for(let i = start; i <= array.length - n; i++) {
     yield* combine(array, n - 1, i + 1, [...prev, array[i]]);
   }
 }

 const result = [...combine([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)];
```

To fullfill your extra requirement, you can skip elements that are already included, like:

```
   if(prev.some(el => compare(el, array[i]))) continue;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look at it when I will be free